# Is there any equivalent in statsmodels of function predict(model, newdata, type="response") from R?

Tags: r, statsmodels

I'm looking for any equivalent in statsmodels of function predict(model, newdata, type="response") from R.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: For which model?

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/dev/generated/statsmodels.base.model.Results.predict.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

`model.predict(newdata)`